# React top level API map not returning children

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render an array of React components to a parent component that takes those children and pass some props to them.

```
const Questions = () => {
const questions = [FullName, DateofBirth, Country]

return (
    <div className={style.BodyContainer}>
      <OnBoarding clientHeight={clientHeight}>
        React.Children.map(questions, child => {
         console.log('CHILD:', child)
         if (React.isValidElement(child)) return React.cloneElement(child, { key: child.name })
         return child
        })
      </OnBoarding>
    </div>
)
export default Questions
}

const OnBoarding = ({ children, clientHeight }) => {

return (
<div className={style.onBoardingContainer}>
        <div className={style.container}>
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
)
export default OnBoarding
}
```

The problem lies in React.Children.map, it is returning nothing for some reason. Because if I use regular array.prototype.map it works. That console.log never gets executed telling me React.Children.map is not even trying to execute because it doesn't accept the array of components.

Note: I need to use the array of components because I have another component that renders these items in order (some kind of minimap to show where you are right now), so having them inside an array allows me to modify only this array and changes will be shown on both components.